# Return modified DataSet

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, asmx, webmethod

I have the following `WebMethod`-

```
[WebMethod]

public DataSet fillGridview(string sql)
{
    using (OdbcConnection cnn = new OdbcConnection(DBcon))
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sql))
        {
            sql = "statement";
        }



        OdbcDataAdapter da = new OdbcDataAdapter(sql, cnn);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "DB.TABLE");

        char tick = (char)0x221A;
        char untick = (char)'x';
        int r = 0;
        foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {

            if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[r]["intValue"].ToString() == "-1")
            {
                ds.Tables[0].Rows[r]["intValue"] = untick + " No";
            }
            else
            {
                ds.Tables[0].Rows[r]["intValue"] = tick + " Yes";
            }

            r = r + 1;

        }


        return ds;

    }
```

This is breaking when trying to convert the `intValue` of either `1`to `√ Yes` or `-1` to `x No`.

The error being -

> Input string was not in a correct format. Couldn't store <√ Yes> in intValue Column.  Expected type is Int32.

Is this possible?

Comment: No... Integer and string are of different types... Although this fancyness can be added when presenting on UI form (in form of strings of course)

Comment: You dont open a connection at any point if I'm not mistaken?

Answer (score 0):

Your column `intValue` is an `Int32` so you can't set it to a `string` value, which is what you are trying to do in your `foreach` loop.

You don't need the `int r = 0;` variable to access rows within your `foreach` loop as you are setting up `DataRow row`, which gives you the current row.

If you're trying to set the value of a column on your GridView to the new string value, you can use the [GridView.RowDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx) event to set the value of one column based on the value in a hidden column.

Or you can add a string column to your DataTable and to bind to that, see below:

```
DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];

dt.Columns.Add("TickedValue", typeof(String));

foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{

    if (row["intValue"].ToString() == "-1")
    {
        row["TickedValue"] = untick + " No";
    }
    else
    {
        row["TickedValue"] = tick + " Yes";
    }        
}
```